# shFileoperation and german Umlaute

Tags: winapi, lazarus

I have this function.

```
procedure DeleteToBin(filename:string);
var
fileOpStruct : TSHFileOpStruct;
filename_a :ansistring;
begin
  filename_a := filename + #0#0;
  //showmessage(filename_a);
  fileOpStruct.Wnd := Application.MainFormHandle;
  fileOpStruct.wFunc := FO_DELETE;
  fileOpStruct.pFrom := PAnsiChar(filename_a); 
  fileOpStruct.fFlags := FOF_ALLOWUNDO + FOF_NOCONFIRMATION;
  SHFileOperation( fileOpStruct );
end;
```

It works nice on ordinary paths and files like: `C:\mypath\myfile.ext`. But as soon I cope with files including german Umlaute it fails eg: `C:\mypööö\myfileüüü.ext`

I tried every conversion I could think of (like UTFtoANSI) but did not get the desired effect.
By the way: the showmessage shows the correct readable german filename.

what kind of conversion is necessary to make it work?

Comment: Well, if you have Unicode Free Pascal, declare your `filename_a` as `string` (assuming the compiler resolves that in a Unicode string type).

Comment: thats where I started (with string). I m using FPC 3.0.4  (x86_64) and as far as I concerned there is Unicodesupport

Comment: You should always zero any structure before using it. Using unicode string, what does `ShFileOperation()` return? It might give a clue, but check the [docs regarding return value](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762164(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: You need to use the Unicode version of SHFileOperation. PAnsiChar is a sign that you are not. Also you need to double null terminate the string.

Comment: OK, I can see your null termination now. Actually you triple null terminated it. Strings are already null terminated, you only need to add one more.

Comment: As @David said, if you are using the Unicode version of SHFileOperation, you must use PWideChar. If not Unicode, you must use PAnsiChar. In Delphi (and probably Freepascal too) the best you can do is to use PChar, which has the correct size depending on the value of the UNICODE define, and the APIs used are the correct ones too. Are you sure you are using a FreePascal that is by default Unicode or is Unicode optional?

Comment: Thanks all for your helpful input. meanwihle i doubt that i have full unicodesupport on shellapi. Even I thaught FPC 3.0.4 has full unicodesupport. Now is there a way to check this reading though the FPC-Site i did not find a downloadlink of an expicit unicodeversion.

Comment: FreePascal 2.7.1+ has `UnicodeString`, but `String` maps to `UnicodeString` ONLY when `{$mode DelphiUnicode}` or `{$ModeSwitch UnicodeStrings}` is used, and they are NOT enabled by default. Also, even when `UnicodeString` is enabled, `UNICODE` is NOT enabled by default, either, so Win32 APIs map to ANSI versions and not Unicode versions. In this situation, you should use `SHFileOperationW()` with `(Unicode|Wide)String`/`PWideChar` explicitly.

Comment: @Remy  this is a verry useful explanation. I will spend another hour in tuning my system.  --- by the way - I found a workaround ... see bellow

Comment: You found a bad workaround, which may fail. You must use Unicode (UTF-16), since there are no APIs accepting UTF-8. AS Raymond Chen said, any Ansi encoding might fail.

Comment: @Remy Ichanged my unit to {$ModeSwitch UnicodeStrings} ans indeed I got widestrings now. Then I changed datatypes to solve the compilererrors. But now using SHFileoperation or SHFileoperationW or Type: TSHFILEOPSTRUCTW I allways get the Error: Incompatible type for arg no. 1: Got _SHFILEOPSTRUCTW, expected LPSHFILEOPSTRUCTW

Comment: @Rudy   funny my example is the only solution that works so far... but i work on it.

Comment: It works on your machine, but you won‘t be shipping your machine.

Comment: thks... but whats the function to convert from utf8 to utf16 ? have not found it on the fly.

Comment: On Windows: MulitByteToWideChar with CP_UTF8 as codepage. But rather use UnicodeString and PWideChar and the -W versions of the API functions. And your error was that you did not take the address of the struct.

Comment: but look at my comment to Remy   ... that gives errors all over the place.... as soon that I work with widestrings ({$ModeSwitch UnicodeStrings}).. and I fear that this could spoil my whole application.

Comment: @ratmalwer like Rudy said, you are passing a record instance where a **pointer to** record instance is expected. Use `SHFileOperationW( @fileOpStruct );` instead of `SHFileOperation( fileOpStruct );`

Comment: @Remy  thanks with your help and utf8Decode it runs now!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Thanks to Remy and David and utf8Decode I got it running this way:
(Edited 2018-04-17)

```
procedure DeleteToBin(filename:string);
var

fileOpStruct : TSHFileOpStructW;
filename_a :string;
begin
  filename_a := utf8Decode('p:\bilder\0_test\mümü.txt' + #0);
  fileOpStruct.Wnd := Application.MainFormHandle;
  fileOpStruct.wFunc := FO_DELETE;
  fileOpStruct.pFrom := PWideChar(filename_a);
  fileOpStruct.fFlags := FOF_ALLOWUNDO + FOF_NOCONFIRMATION;

  showmessage(inttostr(SHFileOperationW( @fileOpStruct )));

end;
```

Comment: You should use UTF16 instead of CP1252. Otherwise you will run into problems with characters that are not in CP1252, or if the system is not using CP1252 as its default 8-bit character set.

Comment: `filename` should be `UTF8String` instead of `string`, and passed to `UTF8Decode()` instead of passing a literal. `filename_a` should be `UnicodeString` instead of `string`

Comment: sure you are right... this is for testing and demonstration... i will implement it soon and give the parameter a decent type

Comment: Even with the edit, you fail to initialize each member of the record.